# Python - variable referenced before assignment

Tags: python, variables

The code I have is:

```
class New(Server):
    noOfCl = 0        

    def onConnect(self, socket):
        print "Client connected"
        print (noOfCl+=1)
```

I am receiving the following error: `UnboundLocalError: local variable 'noOfCl' referenced before assignment.` From what I understand, I'm declaring noOfCl before I am referencing it. Anyone have any ideas as to what I'm doing wrong?
 Thanks

Comment: This code does not throw the error you describe. It throws a plain `NameError`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As `noOfCl` is a Class Variable you need to prefix the Class Name before it.

```
class New(Server):
    noOfCl = 0        

    def onConnect(self, socket):
        print "Client connected"
        New.noOfCl+=1
        print(New.noOfCl)
```

Also your in-place update when calling the `print` function/statement is not supported in Python.

Comment: The parentheses after `print` are redundant

Comment: @San4ez: Depends whether its 3.x or 2.x. This will work irrespective of the Python's Version.